# AttributeError: namespace object has no attribute 'accumulate'

Tags: python, argparse

Here is my current code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Optic disc segmentation.')
parser.add_argument('-f', dest='file', action='store', type=str, help='The image to process.')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

And I keep getting this error on the last line:

```
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'accumulate'
```

Comment: Explaining what issue you're having and what you expect as the end result would be a good idea.

Comment: i am having an error in print (args.accumulate(args.integers))

Comment: Where is the code for `parse_args()` method? What class does object `args` belong to?

Comment: what makes you think `.accumulate` even exists?

Comment: The only attribute of `args` that your code defines is `file`, in the call to `add_argument()`. Your code does not define `args.integers` or `args.accumulate()`. That is the reason for the *no attribute* error.

Comment: @pavel `argparse` is a standard library module.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you directly copied the [argparse Example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#example) but did not understand the usage:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

The [`parse_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method) method creates a [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object, for storing the attributes from the previous calls to [`add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument):

> **ArgumentParser.parse_args(args=None, namespace=None)**
> Convert argument strings to objects and assign them as attributes of the namespace. Return the populated namespace.

The reason why `args` in the example has `accumulate` and `integers` is because of the 2 previous calls to `add_argument`: a positional argument "integers" and one optional one with `dest='accumulate'`. **They are not built-in methods of the object returned by `parse_args`**. They depend on the calls to `add_argument`.

In your example:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Optic disc segmentation.')
parser.add_argument('-f', dest='file', action='store', type=str, help='The image to process.')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

You only made 1 call to `add_argument` with a `dest='file'` param, so `args` will only have a `file` attribute, which should contain whatever is passed to `-f` option.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Optic disc segmentation.')
>>> parser.add_argument('-f', dest='file', action='store', type=str, help='The image to process.')
>>> args = parser.parse_args()
>>> args
Namespace(file=None)
```

So, the only thing to print is `print(args.file)` which will get a value when you call it as

```
$ python test.py -f "/path/to/some/file"
/path/to/some/file
```

I recommend checking out more of the examples in the [`add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method) method.